# Force re-approve on Firebase Twitter Auth

Tags: javascript, twitter, firebase-authentication

I am building a web app to which users login with their Twitter account.
I am building with Firebase JS SDK, and have been able to let users login with their twitter account with the following code:

```
const provider = new firebase.auth.TwitterAuthProvider();
    const result = await firebase.auth().signInWithPopup(provider);
    setMe(result.additionalUserInfo?.profile);
    setToken({
      oauthToken: result!.credential!.accessToken,
      oauthTokenSecret: result!.credential!.secret,
    });
```

The issue I am facing is that once a user logs in with a certain Twitter credentials, log out, and log in again, the user automatically logs in with the original Twitter account, and cannot log in with any other Twitter account.

Is there any way I can force Twitter account re-approve every time the user attempts login?

Comment: It sounds like Firebase is caching something on the client side to remember the account chosen. Is there a way to reset or destroy the Firebase cache?